# removing objects from session R

Tags: r

After hours struggling with the issue I need to ask you for help - how to remove objects from a session in R (R Studio).
I created them as cross sessions:

```
displayed <<- c("D4")
```

But for testing purposes, I have to delete them before running the code. I tried many methods:

```
displayed<<-NULL
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
rm(list=ls())
```

and still both debugging and code logic indicate they exist in the next lines:

```
if (!exists('displayed')){
  displayed <<- c("D4")
  displayedspaces<<-c("4195")
}
```

How can I kill them without Domestos or restarting R Studio? I basically need to test it for further deployment in Shiny and do not want to keep restarting the system or waiting until the time to sleep elapses.

PLEASE NOTE:
It is `<<-` so it is not a local object; it is a session object.

NOTE II:
Gregor's idea works, Spacedman, Jonathan the code (simplified) was easy: i created an object in Global by `<<-`, it was a spatial dataframe (here of course a list to simplify), so there was not any other way - you can't create empty one. Then I tried 3 deletion methods from the 2nd quotation:

```
displayed<<-NULL
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
rm(list=ls()
```

and checked via `browser()` if it existed (it did) and ran (`!exists`) - and it did as well. I do not know why nullification did not work but the next 2 methods simply cleared a local instance I presume, contrary to what have been advised in few other threads on SO.

Comment: Try `rm(list = ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)`?

Comment: Please try and create a self-contained script that we can run that shows the problem. Its possible that you are running things in contexts that we can't duplicate with the scraps you've given us.

Comment: Well, it's not very clear but it seems that you want to delete a variable of the global environment from inside a function for instance. The solution suggested by Gregor should work. Anyway, I recommand using `assign` instead of `<<-`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "*and still both debugging and code logic indicate they exist in the next lines*:"? are you checking for the existence in `.GlobalEnv`?